# How do I validate a certificate by hand?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

I have a website, which has a signed certificate file (`website.crt`) from a certificate authority (CA).

**How do I make sure exactly, that this certificate is valid?**

I know, that browsers do it automatically, but I want to do it by hand, with tools like openssl, so I can learn about the process, and understand what browser do exactly.

Let's assume, that I have one root certificate on my computer, and that there are other intermediate authorities. Also, for the sake of accuracy, it uses x.509 version 3 standard.

Comment: Section 6 of RFC 5280 describes the certificate validation process: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy all CA certificates in PEM format including root into a single file. Certificate can be mostly in one of these two formats: PEM format is text, DER is binary. If it is in DER - can convert this way:

```
openssl x509 -in <certificate in DER> -inform DER -out <certificate in PEM> -outform PEM
```

Then concatenate all CA certificates in PEM format into a single file:

```
cat cert1.cer >> all_certs.cer
cat cert2.cer >> all_certs.cer
```

Then validate your certificate against this certificate chain:

```
openssl verify -CAfile all_certs.cer <your certificate>
```

Comment: (1) that `cp` syntax doesn't work on Unix (and `cp` doesn't exist on Windows) (2) commandline `verify` doesn't check revocation by default, and only has options for CRL not OCSP which is now more common in browsers (except Chrome which uses Google-chosen checks) (3) `verify` also doesn't check 'purpose' (EKU) or hostname by default -- or policies, but I don't know if browsers do those

Comment: (1) mistake, replaced cp with cat in my answer. Thanks for correction. On Windows you can accumulate CA certificates in a notepad. (2) yes, command verify checks only whether the whole certificate chain is trusted. what else do you need to check? Please list and I will add it (3) you are right, you need to check it manually